# Как отправлять запросы, когда сайт не открыт?

Tags: веб-программирование, запрос, push-уведомления

Какие технологии используют такие почтовые сервисы, как Gmail, VK почта, Outlook, чтобы отправлять уведомления о новых сообщениях, даже когда сайты не открыты?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обоснуйте свой дизлайк

Comment: В документации Firefox подробно расписано https://support.mozilla.org/ru/kb/veb-push-uvedomleniya-v-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В подобных задачах используют [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Push_API) и [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).